# conduit http streaming to file (sinkFile) avoid file creation when http returns error

Tags: haskell, conduit

What is a value that I need to return from the getSrc when the http code is unsuccessful and I wish **not** to create a file (by *sinkFile*)
If i just return *getResponseBody res* the http error itself is saved into the file.

```
downloadURL :: String -> FilePath -> IO ()
downloadURL url location = do
  request <- parseRequest url
  runResourceT
         $ runConduit$  httpSource request getSrc
         .| sinkFile location
   where
     getSrc res = do
         let success = statusIsSuccessful . getResponseStatus $ res
         if success then
            getResponseBody res
         else
            ???
```

Comment: What is that you are trying to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kartin's solution should work just fine. Another approach you could take would be to use `sinkFileCautious` instead of `sinkFile`, and throw a runtime exception on an invalid status code. In fact, you could replace `parseRequest` with [`parseUrlThrow`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-11.13/http-client-0.5.12.1/Network-HTTP-Client.html#v:parseUrlThrow) to automatically get this behavior.

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, you want to pipe the response body to some conduit if the response was successful and an alternate conduit in case the response wasn't successful.

I believe that the easiest solution would involve "choosing" a conduit using the `if ... then ... else` you already have in your code - something like

```
module Main where

import Conduit ( printC
               )
import Data.Conduit ( runConduitRes
                    , (.|)
                    , yield
                    )
import Data.Conduit.Binary ( sinkFile
                           )
import Network.HTTP.Simple ( parseRequest
                           , httpSource
                           , getResponseStatus
                           , getResponseBody
                           )
import Network.HTTP.Types.Status ( statusIsSuccessful
                                 )

main :: IO ()
main = do
  requestText <- init <$> readFile "notes/request.txt"
  downloadURL requestText "notes/sink.txt"

downloadURL :: String -> FilePath -> IO ()
downloadURL url location = do
  request <- parseRequest url
  runConduitRes (httpSource request processResponse)
    where
  processResponse response =
    if statusIsSuccessful (getResponseStatus response)
    then (getResponseBody response) .| sinkFile location 
    else yield "an alternate operation" .| printC
```

You can replace the `yield "an alternate operation" .| printC` with another conduit that does what you actually want.

Note that now `sinkFile location` is only executed in the success case so the failure case doesn't create any files.